# Notepad++ enviornment to be more like Dreamweaver

Tags: plugins, dreamweaver, notepad++

I'm trying to adjust to this notepad++ environment currently.

1) Is there a way to create an new xhtml/php/css/etc file in np++ like dreamweaver? ( template files with the doctype and main tags included)

2) Can notepad++ open connecting files like Dreamweaver? like how DW opens all connecting css/js/php includes automatically.

It's really simple compared to Dreamweaver, so I'm trying to adjust to the changes.

Comment: Notepad++ is just a text editor with bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2):

1) Not really.  You would have to create the template file manually and then just open it and Save As.

2) No.

> It's really simple compared to Dreamweaver, so I'm trying to adjust to the changes.

It's also free and thus is not going to have as many features as something like Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just editing styler.xml (if you do not have the styler.xml then go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\themes\ and create one) to get a Dreamweaver style look, but not exactly what Dreamweaver is look like. Dreamweaver use Source Code Pro 10pt font for his code appearance.

Here is a link where you can get a similar style https://gist.github.com/chrismar035/272115

So you can change the default font fontName="Consola" to fontName="Source Code Pro", before that download this font from web.

Now when you done Open Notepad++ go to Setting > Style Configurator and select your theme that is styler.xml.